# How many homomorphisms are there $t: \mathbb{Z}_3 \times U_8 \to S_5$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

This was a question in our quiz today and no one in class knew how to answer it correctly or are not sure).

> How many homomorphisms are there $t: \mathbb{Z}_3 \times U_8 \to S_5$, where $U_8$ is the group of invertible elements in $(\mathbb{Z}_8, \cdot)$.

I personally described it like this:

> A homomorphism as such is given by a homomorphism $t_1 : \mathbb{Z_3} \to S_5$ and $t_2 : U_8 \to S_5$. Therefore the requested number is the number of $t_1$'s $\times$ the number of $t_2$'s.

Here my professor stopped me and told me that that is wrong. But I also would like feedback on the next part:

> I counted $t_1$'s as $20$, because $1$ has to go to $3$-cycles and there are $20$ as such. I counted $t_2$ by saying that the order of every element in $U_8$ is $2$ so every element $t_2(x)$'s order must divide 2, so they can only go to a transposition or a product of two disjoint transpositions. I counted and that got me $40$.

And so, my final answer was $800$, unreasonable number.

I'd like also to get feedback on what is the correct approach to this, as I just lost all points on this question

Comment: Your reasoning would apply if you were asked for the number of homomorphisms $S_5\to \mathbb{Z}_3\times U_8$, but here it doesn't work because you don't have the required universal property.

Comment: @ArnaudD. and would my answer be correct?

Comment: Yes, in that case you could just count the homomorphisms $S_5\to \mathbb{Z}_3$ and $S_5\to U_8$. Your idea would also work if you replaced $S_5$ with an abelian group.

Comment: Any of the elements could also map to the identity of $S_5$.

Comment: I'll Just Outilne The Idea: Let $f\colon G:=\mathbb{Z}_3\times U_8\longrightarrow S_5$ be a homomorphism. Then from the first isomorphism theorem you have $$G/\mathrm{Ker(f)}\cong\mathrm{Im(f)}.$$ Since $G$ is abelian of order $12$ you obtain the following: 1) Every subgroup of $G$ is normal & 2) $\#\{H\ :\ H\leq G\}=10.$
Now, for every $H\leq G$ determine the quotients $G/H$. Next, for every quotient $G/H$ check if there exists any $\tilde{H}\leq S_5$ such that $$G/H\cong \tilde{H}.$$ If yes then count how many there are and then count carefully to compute the number of homomorphisms!